# set directory root

Tags: .htaccess, directory, root

I have a subdirectory for a website:
www.example.com/admin

I'm using includes throughout the site that all use the same path structure:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
```

The stylesheets also have links in them for things like background images.

My problem is that the includes don't work in the /admin directory because they all refer to /assets/css or whatever folder that are all up one level. (Those links work fine for the main website in the root directory, but no good for the admin area.)

Anyone got any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add a `/` to your link (making it an absolute URI instead of the relative URI that it is):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/styles.css">
```

Or you can add a URI base in your page headers:

```
<base href="/">
```